# Insert Into Not Inserting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The code below runs with no errors although it does not insert anything into my database:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","teachme");
//check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//add details in database
if (isset($_POST['user']) and isset($_POST['pass']) and isset($_POST['division'])) {
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $division = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['division']);
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division, id)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division)");
    echo 'Succesfully added entries onto the database.. ';
    echo $user;
    echo $pass;
    echo $division;
    echo '<a href="../">Return to homepage</a>';
}
else {
    echo "An error occured, try again!";
}
?>
```

All the variables are transferred correctly, that is why I used the echo statement above.
I'm new and I know this must be a very stupid question.
[image: Database]

Comment: Are you sure that the query is even being run at all?  Are you sure that error reporting is on and up?

Comment: It's on. The database is still empty after trying all the suggestions.

Comment: Paste the echoed query.

Comment: You mean the username, password and division? These just contain text.

Comment: You are not checking the return of `mysqli_query`.  Without checking, your "Successfully added entries onto the database" is a lie.

Comment: How would I check? It executes with no errors.

Comment: What?? Errormessage: Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division, id)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division)");
```

As your current query is trying to insert into a column, you have referenced 4 column names but included 3 variable reference.

If you have your database to

Auto_increment for ID, your query can be:

```
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division)");
```

If not. You will need to create a variable which is updated per row to fill the `id` column reference.

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division, id)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division, $ID_Placeholder)"); // This will not work without a reference. Take this as an example only
```

---

Just to test that this is the problem, perform an insert by running this:

```
$ID_Placeholder = 4; // just a dummy test variable, to check the insert but also show you where you have went wrong. 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division, id)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division, $ID_Placeholder)");
```

Comment: Nope.. database is still empty. Error reporting is on.

Comment: Are you columns matching up in order?

Comment: @Tom stupid question. Have you clicked browse? as shown here: http://tinypic.com/r/30ll1qa/6

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division, id)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division)");
```

Your column count does not match. You're trying to fill 5 columns with 3 values. Just set "null" in the value clause  or remove the unnecessary "destination" columns.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the fact that there is a mismatch between the number of fields in the `INSERT` statement and the number of values being supplied as noted above, I believe you need to quote the values too, like this:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (username, password, division)
VALUES ('$user', '$pass', '$division')");
```

`mysql_real_escape_string` will handle escaping of single quotes in the variables themselves but it won't quote them for you.

In addition, check the following:

1. `mysqli_query` will return TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the INSERT was successful; if it returns FALSE, call `mysqli_error` to find out what happened.
2. Look into replacing this code with a prepared statement; see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for information and examples.

Answer (score 0):

1. [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#refsect1-function.mysql-real-escape-string-notes) - do not use it.

   > If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments.
   >   Do not use mysql_* at all.
2. Do not use escaping. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).
3. Check documentation of using functions ([mysqli_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues)).
4. Mysql errors are not PHP error. If you want to see MySQL errors use [mysqli_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: My error message: Errormessage: Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

Comment: @Tom, please echo generated query. I do not know what you have in your $_POST.

Comment: I have 'test' in $user, 'test123' in $pass and 'junior' in $division

Comment: @Tom, provide full result query.

Comment: What do you mean? I have just that in my $_POST variables.

Comment: @Tom, let us see full rendered query instead of `INSERT INTO users (username, password, division, id)
VALUES ($user, $pass, $division)`